# passing an image from javascript and store it in database

Tags: javascript, laravel, cropper

how to pass this to controller in laravel

```
canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {

                let formData = new FormData();

                formData.append('path', blob);
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,

                }
                );

            });
```

it only return token
so any one can help i was thinking about this for days!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

formData.append('file', blob, fileName);

contentType: '',

fileName is name of the file.
Alse refer below link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append